# Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const todoSchema = new Schema({
    Todo:{
        Type:String,
        required:true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('todo', todoSchema)
```

I'm trying to connect backened from MongoDB compass so I created a schema but this error occurred: "Invalid schema configuration"

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, it is essential to adhere to the naming convention where the property name for specifying the type should be written in lowercase as "type" instead of "Type". This is crucial because Mongoose expects the property name to be exactly "type" when defining the data type of a field. Additionally, it's better to check if a model already exists.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const todoSchema = new Schema({
   Todo: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   } 
});

module.exports = mongoose.models.todo || mongoose.model('todo', todoSchema);
```